# Forma de la matriz de entrada LSTM | Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

Estoy teniendo problemas para entender la entrada de una red LSTM en keras. Estoy guiándome con este diagrama

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no termino de entender como eso se representa en un array numpy

Por ejemplo, si tengo una serie temporal muy simple 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 (suponiendo el mismo intervalo de tiempo para cada número) y quiero predecir que viene luego del 10 ¿Cómo lo transformo a una matriz 3D?

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias formas de transformar las dimensiones de un array, y con *Numpy* es sencillo. Simplemente tienes que hacer que tenga las mismas dimensiones que la capa de entrada.

### 1. Reshape

Basicamente es **cambiar la forma de tu array a la que desees**, siempre que sea matemáticamente posible, es decir, no puedes cambiar de un array (3) a una matriz (4,4). Te pongo un ejemplo tomando como referencia una parte del array que has puesto, y **te explico con comentarios:**

```
import numpy as np

#Nos creamos un array cualquiera, es una matriz (4,4)
array_temporal = np.array([[1,2,3,4],
                           [2,3,4,5],
                           [3,4,5,6],
                           [4,5,6,7]])

#Podemos pasar una matriz (4,4) a un vector (16) con Reshape
array_1D = array_temporal.reshape(16,)
#Si consultamos sus dimensiones con ndim, vemos que efectivamente es un vector.
print(array_1D.ndim)
#También podemo ver su forma con el método .shape()
print(array_1D.shape)

#Aquí hacemos lo mismo pasándolo a tres dimensiones (probablemente lo que necesites hacer para tu capa de Keras)
array_3D = array_temporal.reshape(1,4,4)
#vemos que tiene 3 dimensiones
print(array_2D.ndim)

#Pero lo podemos formar de cualquier tipo mientras que matemáticamente sea posible. Aquí otro tipo de forma de agruparlo en 3D.
array_3D_2 = array_temporal.reshape(4,2,2)
print(array_3D_2.ndim)

#Y aquí otra vez, está en 4D
array_4D = array_temporal.reshape(2,2,2,2)
print(array_4D.ndim)
```

Mientras que matemáticamente sea correcto, **puedes agregar tantas dimensiones como quieras**, simplemente poniendo 1, ya que cualquier número multiplicado por uno, es el mismo número. Por ejemplo 10 dimensiones:

```
print(array_temporal.reshape(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,4,4))
```

**Output:**

```
array([[[[[[[[[[[1, 2, 3, 4],
                [2, 3, 4, 5],
                [3, 4, 5, 6],
                [4, 5, 6, 7]]]]]]]]]]])
```

### 2.expand_dims

Con esta función puedes expandir las dimensiones, **igual que con el método** `reshape()`. En este caso basandonos en el código anterior, podemos hacer lo siguiente:

```
array_3D_3 = np.expand_dims(array_temporal, axis=0)
print(array_3D_3.ndim)
print(array_3D_3.shape)
```

Como puedes ver has hecho lo mismo que hicimos con `array_temporal.reshape(1,4,4)`. Aquí tendrás que controlar el parámetro `axis` para saber donde quieres añadir la dimensión.

### Conclusiones.

Hay estás formas y más, de cambiar las dimensiones de los datos, estás son las más conocidas. Particularmente me gusta más el método `.reshape()` ya que escribes menos código, es más "matemático", y te permite manipular más fácil de cualquier forma tus datos. Pero esto ya es mi opinión personal, tú usa el que más te guste.